# Reserve memory for a program

Tags: memory

Is it at all possible to set aside say 50MB of memory so that in an emergency where something uses all my memory or loads the CPU I could open a terminal, find the offending process, and kill it?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know that's not possible. And I think it is a much more complicated problem to solve than it looks at first if we take the complexity of memory management into account. It may be even hard to clearly write down what it means to "set 50MB aside".

But in Linux, there is something that may well solve your problem much more elegant:
The OOM killer - out of memory killer - that makes a decision which process to kill if memory gets to tight, and just kills it.
Much better than waiting for the first program that does not check the return value of `malloc()` and chrashes.

There are some parameters to configure it to your needs - see 
[How to Configure the Linux Out-of-Memory Killer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/oom-killer-1911807.html).

Part of what makes it complicated is that it does not help to reserve memory for one program: to do anything useful, you need to be able to start other programs - like `kill`.

Comment: Just a note, `malloc()` failures and the OOM killer are pretty much exclusive. If the OOM killer is enabled, `malloc()` won't return failure. If `malloc()` returns failure, OOM killer is disabled. (There are a few exceptions to this, such as trying to `malloc()` 30PB of memory)

Comment: The OOM killer never seems to work for me. I have run programs design specifically to waste all memory and then trigger the OOM killer and I had to do a hard shutdown. I will look into configuring it.

Comment: Did you actually access that memory? In a way that will not be optimized away by either the compiler or the processor?